# JavaScript/jQuery Syntax error post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on line 27 I have this issue but I think just not this
please find me error

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("submit", "form",function (event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var timeout = null;
                 $.ajax({
                    url:form.attr("action"),
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/";
                        if(typeof data  == "object"){
                            if(data.error === true || data.error === "true"){
                            }else if(data.error === false || data.error === "false"){
                                alert("trueeeee");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("button[type='submit']",form).removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("loading");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                        },6000)
                    }
                });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of missing closing brackets...

Comment: Worth formatting the page so it is easier to see, as @VLAZ mentioned it will be closing brackets.Shame you've been voted down, it's a fair started question. Take time, use something like Visual Studio and keep on with SO. :-)

Comment: @indofraiser the downvotes aren't for the *asker*. They are rating the question. And this question isn't very helpful - yes, we all make typos. I've not kept track but I'd hazard a guess that I personally mess up brackets more than once a day on average. However, typographical questions aren't useful to other visitors as each situation will be unique. Moreover, brackets, correct syntax and similar are one of the first things that an aspiring programmer will need to learn to recognise and deal with anyway for the rest of their career. It's a normal problem to have but not a good Q&A to have.

Comment: @VLAZ Fair point. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you close **every** curly brace or bracket. You add `}) })` and it should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("submit", "form",function (event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var timeout = null;
                 $.ajax({
                    url:form.attr("action"),
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/";
                        if(typeof data  == "object"){
                            if(data.error === true || data.error === "true"){
                            }else if(data.error === false || data.error === "false"){
                                alert("trueeeee");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("button[type='submit']",form).removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("loading");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                        },6000)
                    }
                });
});
});
</script>
```